# Nuxt Using component in slot, vuex store is undefined

Tags: vuex, nuxt.js, element-ui, vue-composition-api

Currently I'm developing with nuxt in typescript with vue-composition API.
leveraging element-ui [tooltip](https://element.eleme.io/2.4/#/en-US/component/tooltip), I put a component inside it's namedslot supposedly name TestComponent.

```
<el-tooltip placement="right">
  <div slot="content">
      <TestComponent/>
  </div>
  TEST
</el-tooltip>
```

In the component i have a call to vuex store

```
<template><div/></template>
import { defineComponent } from '@vue/composition-api'
import { telemetrySetup } from './composition/telemetry'

export default defineComponent({
  setup (_, context) {
    console.log(context.root) // Cannot find $store in here
  }
})
```

Is this expected?

Comment: I am not familiar with the composition API but putting a component inside a slot should not cause such problem. Did it work when you tried putting the component outside a slot?

Comment: @Komninos yes, it works fine.
I wonder why since the vuex is registered in vue instance itself

it should be available where ever the scope is

Comment: update: I just create my own component with slot and plug my component using vuex. it seems fine, it could be bug(?) from element ui itself

Comment: What you're saying is correct. It could either be a bug in the library or maybe you have missed something else. I very much doubt it being a Nuxt/Vue problem though. I would suggest opening an issue on their [Github page](https://github.com/ElemeFE/element) if you don't manage to find a solution but they already have a lot to go through so I do not know how fast you'll get a response.

Comment: Or you could also see the source file of the element you're using and debug it yourself. The file is located [here](https://github.com/ElemeFE/element/blob/dev/packages/tooltip/src/main.js), just make sure you are using the appropriate package version since the file I linked to is in the `master` branch

Comment: it could be because somehow it wraps the "content" inside interpolation.....

Comment: I have the same issue, Nuxt, with my Vue component library as external package. My custom component use nested slot to pass external slot into it's own child component. After this manipulation, the `$store` and `$router` variables are no longer available in the Vue instance of the slot. While `$vuetify` and `$_apolloInitData` for example, remain.. The `$parent` variable is available but `null`